# Need some help with decryption code for monoalphabetic substitution

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, classical-cipher, substitution-cipher

I am working on decrypting ciphertext in monoalphabetic substitution algorithm. I tried to decrypt using frequency histogram of English alphabets individually. The [percentage of these frequencies can be found here](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Emec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html), but the plaintext I got from this was not informative. So I tried searching online and found [this website](https://www.dcode.fr/monoalphabetic-substitution) for decrypting monoalphabetic substitution. The result was amazing in this site and they used digrams for decryption. So I tried using digrams but the results I got was not good.

Can someone guide me through this decryption?

[Link for my code](https://github.com/devcoder46/substitutioncipher/blob/main/monoalphabeticcipher.py)